# Book recommendation for Mahabharata in Hindi

Tags: mahabharata, book-recommendation

I am planning to read Mahabharata. Can anyone tell me a good book written in Hindi

Comment: Mahabharata is a vast topic. Can you  specify on what topic you want to get recommendation?

Comment: @SreeCharan I think its pretty clear from the question that he wants to read `The Mahabharata` of Srila Vyasadeva complete with 18 parva. and not a certain topic within it.

Comment: @PrakashK Yes you are right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mahabharata of [Geeta Press Gorakhpur](http://www.gitapress.org) is the most famous version available in Hindi language.

> [image]   [image]   [image]

It is available in multiple sets and is a huge book. You can directly buy from their [website](http://gitapressbookshop.in/books-by-topics-subjects/mahabharat.html) or store or from some website like [this](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/complete-mahabharata-only-edition-with-sanskrit-text-and-hindi-translation-six-volumes-NZA120/).

Alternatively, if you wish to read it online then you can download its pdf version from [here](https://archive.org/details/MahabharatYear1Vol.5GitaPressGorakhpur). Note these are volumes named as [**Year  1 vol.  5**](https://archive.org/details/MahabharatYear1Vol.5GitaPressGorakhpur) and [**Year 3 vol. 1**](https://archive.org/details/MahabharatYear3Vol.1GitaPressGorakhpur) etc. So searching for necessary Parva / chapter is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to buy Mahabharata in Hindi, then buy from [Vedrishi.com](https://www.vedrishi.com/book/mahabharat/) here you will get Mahabharata free from adulteration, many fictionious stories. With Complete of 16 thousand of Verses. In time of Maharaja Bhoja, Only 25000 verses are available. Many controversy if you want to know then go on YouTube Channel [Thanks Bharat](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_VejhvwHK5seDBmgnWlpRMP1qJKQJ1UZ). After Invasion of Muslims then Mahabharata verses goes in 25000 to 45000 to 80000 then last at the time in modern times to around 103000 verses.